# Assign the key of TypeScript enum to variable

Tags: typescript, enums

I have the following string enum:

```
export enum ReportGraphTypes {
    OverallGraph = "Long description...",
    OverallByDateGraph = "....",
    MilageGraph = "....",
    FuelPricesGraph = "....",
    FuelConsumptionGraph = "...."
}
```

Then I map the enum to select field and use the enum key as a value.
I want to pass a default value to my select field and always can do the following:
`let selected = "OverallGraph";` but that's hardcoded.
I also tried:
`let selected = ReportGraphTypes[ReportGraphTypes.OverallGraph];` but I got the following error:
`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'ReportGraphTypes.FuelPricesGraph' can't be used to index type 'typeof ReportGraphTypes'.`
What is the best way to assign that key to my variable?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using the `keyof typeof` operators to get the keys? I typically use the same approach of your second solution and I hadn't had any problems with it myself so far. Perhaps it's because that approach only works for `number` type values. But maybe you could use a map object instead.

Comment: I tried also `keyof typeof` but still: `Conversion of type 'ReportGraphTypes' to type '"OverallGraph" | "OverallByDateGraph" | "MilageGraph" | "FuelPricesGraph" | "FuelConsumptionGraph"' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.ts(2352)`
I guess I have to switch to map.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like string enums have an odd behavior. There’s an open issue about this very error on github. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29094